# Android Phones not opening PDF streamed after postback in ASP.Net Site

Tags: c#, android, asp.net, pdf

I have an ASP.Net site that streams back a PDF document after a postback to the initial page.  In IE, Chrome, Firefox, and on iPhones and iPads, everything works fine, the PDF is sent to the browser.  On Android phones, I get an error stating that the PDF is invalid.  The code below is a simplified version of what I am trying to do, but it does reproduce the error.  I basically have a button on a web page that is set to run at server.  On the first request of the page it displays the HTML and after the button click, it should render the PDF:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    Response.ClearHeaders();
    Response.AppendHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache"); //HTTP 1.1
    Response.AppendHeader("Cache-Control", "private"); // HTTP 1.1
    Response.AppendHeader("Cache-Control", "no-store"); // HTTP 1.1
    Response.AppendHeader("Cache-Control", "must-revalidate"); // HTTP 1.1
    Response.AppendHeader("Cache-Control", "max-stale=0"); // HTTP 1.1 
    Response.AppendHeader("Cache-Control", "post-check=0"); // HTTP 1.1 
    Response.AppendHeader("Cache-Control", "pre-check=0"); // HTTP 1.1 
    Response.AppendHeader("Pragma", "no-cache"); // HTTP 1.1 
    Response.AppendHeader("Keep-Alive", "timeout=3, max=993"); // HTTP 1.1 
    Response.AppendHeader("Expires", "0"); // HTTP 1.1 

    if (IsPostBack)
    {
        Response.ClearContent();
        Response.ClearHeaders();

        string fullPath = @"C:\Temp\outdoc.pdf";

        if (System.IO.File.Exists(fullPath))
        {

            //Set the appropriate ContentType.
            Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
            //Response.ContentType = "application/octet-stream";
            Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=\"TestDoc.pdf\"");

            byte[] b = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(fullPath);
            this.Page.Response.AddHeader("Content-Length", b.Length.ToString());

            //Write the file directly to the HTTP content output stream.
            Response.BinaryWrite(b);
            Response.Flush();
            Response.End();
            Response.Close();

        }
    }


}
```

I have played a lot with different values in the headers and different ways of closing and flushing the response stream with no luck.  Has anyone seen this before or can anyone offer any suggestions on things to try.

Edit:  I have found out that this only happens when I do a postback to the page.  If I just stream the document right off the bat, the document streams correctly.  This leads me to believe it is some sort of caching problem with the android browser.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try transfer current request to other handler where you render PDF directly to response stream.

Your page code:

```
if (IsPostBack)
{
  Context.Server.Transfer("RenderPDF.ashx");
  Response.End();
}
```

And in that new **RenderPDF.ashx**, move here that code responsible for rendering pdf file.

Comment: Thanks.  I'll give this a shot and let you know.

Answer (score 0):

Android does not seem to like `Content-Disposition` much, from what I can tell. I recommend writing the PDF out to a file and issuing a redirect to the URL pointing to that file.

Comment: This isn't a good solution for me, as in my real solution, I am streaming data from a DB to create the PDF and I don't want a transitory copy sitting on a server.  I am then stuck with a lot of problems of cleaning up files and ensuring uniqueness of names.  Also, this doesn't seem to be a problem if I don't do a postback, which I have found out and will add to the original post.

Comment: @John Koerner: "I don't want a transitory copy sitting on a server" -- stick it in a specific directory and clean up older PDF files nightly with a `cron` job. "and ensuring uniqueness of names" -- use a GUID.

Comment: The problem is that I am decrypting some data based on the user's input and I cannot have the decrypted data live on the server's file system for any period of time.